# Constructor handling exception and using this keyword Java

Tags: java, exception, constructor, this

I have two constructors for my class, one that takes `File` object and the other takes a `String` object, and I want to use the `this` keyword. The function with the implementation is the one with `File` as parameter, and the one with `String` will call `this`. Now I want to check for exception in the constructor that takes `String` but I get error, that `this` should be the first line. How can I check for errors then call `this`.

Here is my code:

```
public Test (String filename) {
    if (filename == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("The String you entered is null.");
    if (filename.isEmpty())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The String you entered is empty.");

    this(new File(filename)); // error
}

public Test (File f) {
    /* implementation here */
}
```

This is the exact error: `Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor`

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The code posted is just opposite of what you described!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is impossible in Java thanks to their arbitrary restrictions. You have two main possibilities.

The more idiomatic Java technique is to wrap everything in a factory function so you can catch the exception. Factory functions are also useful because they let you create objects polymorphically, and help hide the details of what object is actually created.

```
public static Test create(String filename){
    if (filename == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("The String you entered is null.");
    if (filename.isEmpty())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The String you entered is empty.");
    return new Test(filename);
}

private Test (String filename) {
    this(new File(filename)); 
}

public Test (File f) {
    /* implementation here */
}
```

The other option is to write the constructor in bytecode, where there are no such restrictions present. Unfortunately, bytecode is less readable and maintainable, so you'll probably want to minimize the amount of bytecode in a primarily Java app. You might also be able do this in a non Java language like AspectJ.

Edit: If you're not actually trying to catch the exceptions, then there's a third possibility. You can insert arbitrary code before the super constructor call by creating a separate function which performs the checks and then passing it as a dummy argument to the super constructor call. Since arguments are evaluated first, your code will run first, but this is a bit of a hack.

```
public Test (String filename) {
    this(doChecks(filename), new File(filename));
}

private static Void doChecks(String filename){
    if (filename == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("The String you entered is null.");
    if (filename.isEmpty())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The String you entered is empty.");
    return null;
}

public Test (Void dummy, File f) {
    this(f);
}

public Test (File f) {
    /* implementation here */
}
```

Comment: The first option, is like to write an `init` function and use it?

Comment: *this is impossible in Java thanks to their arbitrary restrictions* : I guess the restrictions are not arbitrary ;)

Comment: @Noob Actually, the restrictions are arbitrary. There's no technical reason for them, though it does simplify the specification slightly.

Comment: I doubt if it weren't a restriction, then we could call an instance method from the constructor, before calling `this` or `super`, which I presume would be wrong because the instance hasn't be fully created yet! Just my guess;)

Comment: @Noob The thing is that the restrictions are not present at the bytecode level. The Java language added them. And no, you aren't allowed to call instance methods on an uninitialized this object, though you are allowed to set fields declared in the same class, and you can run arbitrary code not related to this.

Comment: It's not arbitrary at all. If we agree that `super()` call must be the first line in the constructor, then there is a very good technical reason that `this()` must be the first line also -- it's the `this()` call that calls the `super()`. As to why `super()` must come first, this is because the superclass constructor does not know about subclasses, and must be able to assume nothing runs before it that can mess with the instance, due to abstraction. C++ also enforces this. In theory it may be possible to relax the restriction so `this` and instance variables cannot be used before `super()`.

Comment: @newacct It's arbitrary in the sense that there's no technical reason for it. The bytecode format supports arbitrary code before the constructor call (with some restrictions on typing). There's no particular reason that the Java compiler couldn't expose this functionality (aside from complicating the JLS). This restriction is purely at the Java level, with no underlying basis in the classfile format. It's not just "in theory". Bytecode can and does behave this way. In fact, it's required to, since people can use complicated expressions as arguments to the constructor call.

Comment: @Antimony: Okay, so basically what you're saying is, a language that compiles into the Java bytecode could allow it. But you do not dispute that there may be good reasons from an object-oriented language design point of view to disallow it.

Comment: @Newacct the only reason to disallow it is to simplify the language specification. Which is admittedly, a pretty good reason, but it has nothing to do with Java being OO. The JLS already has rules about definite assignment, so it wouldn't be too hard to add similar rules for uninitialized this.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot check for errors before call `this`. It's forbidden by the specification. In fact, you didn't need it. Let `new File(filename)` to throw exceptions.

edit: I saw aizen92's comment: [Actually that is what my constructor with the implementation has, it catches the exception may be thrown by file, so I just add the null exception and use this directly in my second constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16121348/constructor-handling-exception-and-using-this-keyword-java/16121381#comment23026117_16121428)

```
public Test (String filename) {
    this((filename == null || filename.isEmpty()) ? null : new File(filename)); 
}
```

Comment: This will throw the wrong exception type when `filename.isEmpty()`.

Answer (score 0):

In case we use `this` or `super` in constructor, either `this` or `super` should be the first statement in the constructor. It is better, if you throw exception from a particular constructor.

```
public Test (String filename) {
    this(new File(filename));
}
```

Let the second constructor handle any exception, caused by passing `null`.

```
public Test (File file) {
    // exception handling code
    // or new instance creation
}
```

Comment: Actually that is what my constructor with the implementation has, it catches the exception may be thrown by file, so I just add the null exception and use `this` directly in my second constructor?